# Javascript double nested for loop traversing

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I am trying to find a way to write this without using a double for loop by either using higher order function or data structures.

I have these two defined type here

```
List = {
    'start' ? : Position

    'end' ? : Position
}

Position = {
    row?: number;
    column?: number;
}
```

This is the for loop that I believe can be optimized or avoid using for loop for.

```
for (let row = list.start.row; row <= list.end.row; row++) {
  for (let col = list.start.column; col <= list.end.column; col++) {
     console.log(`row: ${row}, col: ${col}`);

  }
}
```

So if the I have the list defined as

```
list.start.row = 2, list.start.column = 4
list.end.row = 3, list.start.column = 6
```

I should have `(2,4) (2,5) (2,6) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6)` output as the console messages and order does not matter. What would be the most optimal way of doing this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your opposition to a nested loop? The complexity will be O(mn) no mater if you use a nested loop or other methods.

Comment: Hm, I guess I just wanted to gain a better understanding of what other ways JavaScript can achieve the same result. However, if this is the cleanest way of doing things, it is fine to leave it alone as well.

Comment: No, there's not. You want - and need - a nested loop, so write one. Of course there are other looping syntaxes available, but it always comes down to the nested loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this with a single loop. In fact its a very common way to navigate multi dimensional arrays in memory. For example, you have a chunk of raw image data, and you want to get the pixel information at `point(80,120)`. You'd have to be able to convert the `(x,y)` coordinates to some offset. This is trivial if you know the width of a row. To get the pixel information, assuming each pixel is 8 bits simply calculate `i = y * width + x`. You can use this same technique to create a multi dimensional array using one loop. You'd have to apply the above formula in reverse to find the `(x,y)` points from `(i, width)`. Computing the width is easy, its the `end.column - start.column` and calculating the number of elements would be the `height * width`. The height is obviously the difference in `rows`. You would then loop through your entire linear domain and project the `i` back to `(x,y)` in your array.

It might be easier to just look at the sample code.

```
const list = {
  start: { row: 2, column: 4 },
  end: { row: 3, column: 6 }
};

const x0 = list.start.column;
const y0 = list.start.row;
const x1 = list.end.column;
const y1 = list.end.row;
const width = x1 - x0 + 1; // range is inclusive so [2,2] has a width of 1.
const height = y1 - y0 + 1; // same here.

const results = Array.from({ length: width * height }, (_, n) => {
  const row =  (n - n % width) / width + y0;
  const column = n % width + x0;
  
  return [row, column];
});

console.log(results);
```

Should you do it instead of a nested loop? Probably not in javascript. Complexity is still O(mn) and so its no faster algorithmically then a nested loop. The compiler/vm will likely optimize a [x,y] nested loop into something like this for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It always will be a nested loop if you want to print all values of `x` for all values of `y`. You can use different syntax, such as `forEach`, but it'll always be the same concept - and the solution you have is actually the most optimal and efficient (as there'll always be `xy` combinations for `x` and `y` values; so if your time complexity is `O(mn)`, it's fine).